# How to solve this numerical integration

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

i have this integration equation, i want to solve it with numerical integration. am no maths pro, so i just need a way to break it down and solve using one of the numerical methods

[image: the integration equation]

i need it broken down or so i can write a program that will numerically integrate it once I input the values of B and the upper limit p.

the value of z depends on the value of p. For every slight change in p, z changes also. The formulas to calculate z is given below:

[image: The equation for z]

The equation for y

[image: The equation for y]

Comment: How does $p$ relate to $t,\,p_{pr}$ and $z$? Is the integral really wrt $p$ and then has $p$ as a limit of integration?

Comment: In addition to Daryl's comment - what language are you using? Mathematics, MATLAB, C, Python, something else entirely?

Comment: Ppr is the same thing as P, its a value that will be provided. am using Force 2.0 ide, probably using fortran77

Comment: I guess you should use the QUADPACK library http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f77_src/quadpack/quadpack.html

Comment: You still haven't answered the important part of Daryl's comment - is the integral really with respect to $p$ and has $p$ as a limit of integration? I'd expect it should be something like $\int_{3}^{p} f(q) \textrm{d}q$.

Comment: @in_wolfram_we_trust am using Force 2.0 ide, probably using fortran77

Comment: yes its with respect to p and has p as a limit of integration

Comment: @Daryl i checkd the website you mentioned, but i dont find exaples related to mine. any help here

Comment: Forgive me for my naivete, but if $p_{pr}=p$, the isn't $z/p$ a constant?  If that is the case, then the integral is trivial.

Comment: p a constant that provided during my calculation, z is calculated from the equation i provided and y is calculated from the equation i just added

Comment: @Smith: sorry, not seeing that equation.

Comment: @RonGordon please check again. thanks

Comment: @Smith: I see it now, thanks.

Comment: $p$ should not be the limit of integration and the variable of integration. Check your derivation of this problem.

Comment: @Arkamis: i dont really understand what yo mean. i got this equation from book. can you explain why?

Comment: @Smith Maybe it's a typo? If we're doing Riemann integration, it doesn't really make sense to have the variable of integration be a limit of integration. Consider $\int_a^x 2x\ dx$. This doesn't really mean anything. We could evaluate this to $x^2\mid_a^x$ but that's just $x^2-a^2$. The proper way to write this would be $\int_a^x 2y\ dy$.

Comment: @Arkamis like i said before, the value of p and B are constants

Comment: @Smith then it makes no sense to integrate with respect to a constant. That would be like writing $\int_a^b x d2$.

Comment: @Arkamis so what is the fix for the equation

Comment: I cannot possibly answer that without some context for how it was derived.

Comment: @Arkamis please assume p in the uper limit is another letter is an arbitiary constant, can you help solve it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Matlab script that may be a good place to start. It sets up $F$ as a vector, finds the root for each value of $p$ and stores that as a vector. This is then used to define a vector containing the value of the function over the integration interval. You then integrate by summing over the vector and multiplying by the line element. You may need greater accuracy when finding the root so you could use the Matlab fzero function as well once you have found roughly where the root is by this method. I can email the file if you think it would be useful. If you don't have Matlab the underlying principal will be the same in another program and you could start from this method except the "sum" and "min" commands may be program specific. Apologies for poor resolution, couldn't get my head round the HTML lark so I used a tiff file...

[image]

Comment: as the commenter mentioned above that the integral equation is not correct. how did you think the solution you provided might be correct. am still trying to find out the correct form. besides i dont see the solution of p, that is the integral. and also, i dont have mathlab, but am using fortran

Comment: OK, first of all the objection they had was that you used the same variable name for the upper limit as you did the integration variable. While this is poor notation, I'm sad to say it happens quite regularly in physics particularly in Electrostatics; for example you might integrate over a changing radial quantity $r$ and still call the outer most limit $r$ so that it appears as a radial quantity in your final expression. That is how I interpreted this integral, a changing pressure and a final pressure but being lazy with the notation.

Comment: The integral is calculated in the last line as a sum over the function $H$ multiplied by the line element $dp$. A very similar code would also work in Fortran, I just checked they have $abs$, $min$ and $sum$ commands.

Comment: I called the upper and lower limits $Pup$ and $Plow$ respectively..

Comment: The equation you are after is the vertical flow equation for bottom hole pressure in natural gas wells, first developed by Sukkar and Cornell in 1955. Their paper is not open access however, but here are a few links to papers deriving similar equations as yours. The first two are lazy and use the same variable name inside the integration as they do in the upper limit:http://www.benthamscience.com/open/topej/articles/V004/1TOPEJ.pdf

Comment: http://www.psig.org/papers/1990/9504.pdf

Comment: the third uses capitals for limits as I did, pg 344 http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7TI516mt3s8C&pg=PA364&lpg=PA364&dq=Direct+calculation+of+bottom-hole+pressures+in+natural+gas+wells&source=bl&ots=TfkHr12ijr&sig=fn7NPtaklVik_Auy6uzefTLAR0U&hl=en&sa=X&ei=oeSEUarmCMLXPdmjgcAN&ved=0CGAQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=Direct%20calculation%20of%20bottom-hole%20pressures%20in%20natural%20gas%20wells&f=false

Comment: thanks for the extra effort, i guess i believe my equation is correct now. how can i test the program you wrote, so i can mark your answer. by the way, are you an engineer of a physicist?

Comment: I will try and put it into Fortran form later today, btw do you have an expression for $B$, I think that may be temperature dependent (I called $t$ time in my code... woops). Also I presume you are operating at a temperature close to the critical temperature such that $t\approx 1$ is that correct? If not $X1\approx 0$ and $Z$ is independent of $p$ which would simplify everything quite a lot. Bit of both... background in theoretical physics but currently apply it to fiber optic communications.

Comment: Also, do you have any idea where you may approximately find the root, $Y$ in $F$? That is, what might be a typical value for $Y$?

Comment: Am suppose to iteratively "guess" the value of y by repeated derivative. I don't know hoe to do this in code, maybe you could help. please check here for the question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379823/repeated-derivative-of-this-function

Comment: What you have described there is known as the Newton Raphson method for finding the root but even that requires an initial guess; you wouldn't need that method if you used the code I have given you because this code uses the $min$ command to automatically find the root if it lies within a given region, either way you have to initially guess roughly where it is. So I was just wondering if you had any idea what it might roughly be? I was guessing between 0.03 and 0.06 because that's where I was finding solutions. Doesn't matter, depends on the other parameters anyway...

Comment: please can you send me the program that satisfy my req. pls check my profile for email. thanks for your help

Comment: I have had a look at converting the program to Fortran but came to the conclusion that as I haven't used it for years I would undoubtedly make numerous coding errors so I am probably not well placed to do the conversion. I can send you the Matlab file and a HTML file or pdf that you could read through to try the conversion yourself, however, I don't see your email displayed on your profile...?

Comment: i will try it out, send it oghenez @ aol . com

Comment: Should be in your inbox.

Comment: i have not been able to successfully convert to fortran, but will let you know if i have any issues. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest (and less acurate) way to numerically integrate is to compute the function in several points equally spaced in [3, p] and them compute the mean of those values multiplied by $p-3$ (Tks Graham and Petr for pointed that! )

Comment: I don't see how this corresponds to the integral, why divide by the number of samples (as you do when taking the mean) and what about multiplying by the line element to account for the x axis scale?

Comment: @GrahamHesketh [Riemann integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral) is defined just as a limit of such means as the distance between the points gets to 0. So the finer spacing of points, the closer to the integral the mean gets.

Comment: @Petr Pudlák I would say that the Rieman integral is the limit of the Rieman sum: $\sum _{i=1}^{n-1}f \left( x_{{i}} \right)  \left( x_{{i+1}}-x_{{i}}
 \right)$ as the interval tends to zero. I don't see how that can be described as the "mean" of the samples $\frac{1}{n}\sum _{i=1}^{n-1}f \left( x_{{i}} \right)$ as the latter is divided by $n$ and not multiplied by the line element  $(x_{{i+1}}-x_{{i}})$; $dx$ in the limit. Are you saying these two sums converge to the same value in the limit? I am struggling to see how that is true when the latter is independent of the x-axis scale...

Comment: @GrahamHesketh Sorry, I was wrong, it's necessary to multiply the mean by $p-3$. Then if we distribute the points evenly so that $x_{i+1}-x_i=\frac{p-3}{n}$ then $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}f(x_i)(x_{i+1}-x_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}f(x_i)\frac{p-3}{n}=\frac{p-3}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}f(x_i)$.

Comment: I would agree with your final equation if you did not multiply the first sum by $(p-3)$, and instead defined $x_{i+1}-x_i=(p-3)\frac{1}{n}$ but I'm guessing that is what you meant?

Comment: I see you fixed that... Thanks for helping me understand Petr.

Comment: Just to clarify, the code I supplied numerically integrates using the method we have discussed i.e. a Rieman sum; see last line. Perhaps I was a little lax when I described this as "summing over a vector".

Comment: Also at some point in this code I describe $F$ as a quartic polynomial; clearly it is not a quartic polynomial but that's not important... :)

Comment: I edited my answer. Thanks you both for pointing the error!